# Bigcommerce app submission - user flow requirements

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm hoping that a Bigcommerce rep can answer this. I had some trouble accessing my Bigcommerce store to get my support PIN so I'm posting here.

I am developing a Bigcommerce app and am wondering if the Bigcommerce user must automatically be logged into my app when they open it in the iframe, or can the app display a login page inside the iframe when it opens?

I've seen some apps first display a signup page for the user to fill out, and I was planning to also first display a signup page for the user to create an account inside the app, then ask them to log into the app on the next session. Is this allowed, or do I need to implement OAuth in a way that allows the Bigcommerce user to log into my app based on their store during the app load?

Thanks

Comment: Um, I don't know, but does bigcommerce do their customer support here? Wouldn't mailing them make more sense than "hoping that a Bigcommerce rep can answer this" on StackOverflow?